# 100% wide footer when body must have margin auto

Tags: html, css

I have made a website that needs to have fixed max body size, to be centered in the middle, i did with max-width and margin: 0 auto, but how can i create a footer that spans 100% of the screen as the last content of body?

The body dont have a fixed size and can be smaller if the content of a specific page is not 400px wide, so it makes it very tricky.

```css
body {
  color: #000066;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
    </p>

    <footer>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur vel ratione laboriosam dignissimos, quas
      temporibus odit harum modi! Reiciendis repudiandae repellendus commodi. Voluptate odio animi aperiam! Fugit ullam
      quibusdam voluptate!
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Does_ it need to have a narrow body, though? That's an odd strategy. You should narrow a container element, not the entire document body. Then your footer can be outside that container and full width.

Comment: If this is merely to have the background color of the footer take up 100% of the body width (and not the content) there are techniques for that too.

Answer (score 1):

you can move it left by the size of the viewport + the size of the body (400px) and the padding (40px)

```css
body {
  color: #000066;
  width: 400px; /* should be fixed width */
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -200px;
  left:calc(-50vw + 200px); /* width of container */
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
      quibusdam, quam nihil pariatur provident consectetur. Omnis totam dolore fugit illo tenetur cumque vitae culpa!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat assumenda, ea doloribus odit aperiam iure,
    </p>

    <footer>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur vel ratione laboriosam dignissimos, quas
      temporibus odit harum modi! Reiciendis repudiandae repellendus commodi. Voluptate odio animi aperiam! Fugit ullam
      quibusdam voluptate!
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```